# how to display file dialog with csv streamed from a server

Tags: javascript

I am using jQuery.doGet() to get a csv file from the server.  I am receiving the contents of the file in the onDataReceived function.  How do I display the file dialog for the user to save it?

adsafe.util.doGet(url, params, onDataReceived);

onDataReceived(data) {
 // how do i launch the file dialog for the user to save this data as a file.
}

Comment: Why does this have to go the jQuery route? Is directly linking to the download not an option?

Comment: yeah, thats what i figured out.  I am a newbie so I didnt know it could be done so simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

Instead of using doGet and then trying to launch the save box myself, I left it to the browser to do everything.

Simply calling

window.location = url

So this, downloads the file and displays the file dialog box.

Is this the right way to do it?  Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Just today I did something similar but I just use `window.open(file)` and then issue the download in the new file.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this, but the problem is a new blank window object is getting opened until the file streaming happens.  Once the file is on the client side the window closes and the save file dialog appears.

Comment: Opps...it got posted before i completed.  So I did window.location = url and it worked!  The browser takes care of downloading the file and displaying the save box.